# How to send commit changes from GitLab to Teams

Tags: curl, gitlab-ci, microsoft-teams

I have a CI that sends a commit message to Teams when a commit is created.

```
Notification:
  before_script: 
    - git show $CI_COMMIT_SHA > /tmp/changes
    - export changelog=$(cat /tmp/changes)
  script:
    - >
      curl --silent --show-error
      --request POST 
      --header 'Content-Type: application/json'
      --url "https://webhook"
      --data '{"@type": "MessageCard","@context": "http://schema.org/extensions","themeColor": "0076D7","summary": "New commit","sections": [{"activityTitle": "New commit","activitySubtitle": "json","activityImage": "https:images","facts": [{"name": "Assigned to","value": "'"$GITLAB_USER_LOGIN"'"},{"name": "Message","value": "'"$CI_COMMIT_MESSAGE"'"},{"name": "Status","value": "'"$CI_JOB_STATUS"'"}]}],"potentialAction": [ {"@type": "OpenUri","name": "Link to the page with changes","targets": [{"os": "default","uri": "'"https://git/-/commit/$CI_COMMIT_SHA"'"}]}]}'
  only:
    - master
  tags: 
  - VM_Mobi_Neo
```

I want to send the changes($changelog) themselves to Teams, does anyone know how I can do that?

Comment: Could you please check this [documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/integrations/microsoft_teams.html). It may help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can integrate Microsoft Teams with GitLab, and display notifications about GitLab projects in Microsoft Teams.

[Configure Microsoft Teams](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/integrations/microsoft_teams.html#configure-microsoft-teams) to enable a webhook to listen for changes.

[Configure your GitLab project](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/integrations/microsoft_teams.html#configure-your-gitlab-project) to push notifications to the Microsoft Teams webhook

Check this [docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/integrations/microsoft_teams.html) more details