# How to send artifact from GitLab to Teams

Tags: curl, gitlab, gitlab-ci, microsoft-teams

I want to send an artifact from GitLab to Microsoft Team using --curl,  does anyone know how I can do that?
The main idea send file as attachment to Teams using curl command.

N.B. [I know how to send a text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67702653/how-to-send-commit-changes-from-gitlab-to-teams), but also need to send attachment.

Comment: You can send attachment using Graph API. Reference doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/message-post-attachments?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#example-file-attachment

Comment: @ChetanSharma-msft I think that's for an email message, not for a Teams message...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think it's possible to attach an -actual- file to a Teams message, rather you can link to a file that sits somewhere else, like most specifically in the SharePoint site for the Team itself, for example. So, you would, as an example:

1. User Graph to upload the file to the SharePoint site for the Team (basically the "Files" tab in Teams)
2. Send a Teams message using Graph, referencing the attachment. Here is an example:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/chatmessage-post?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#example-4-send-a-message-with-file-attachment-in-it